# My sql order substring colum value by count

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to order my query by counts of the substring.

Table :

id  shop_update

```
1  a,b,c
2  a,b
3  c
4  a,'',c
```

I just to order this by count

```
id  shop_update count
 1   a,b,c       3
 2   a,b         2
 3   c           1
 4   a,'',c      2
```

My query is

```
$this->db->select("*,LENGTH(shop_update) - LENGTH(REPLACE(shop_update,',','')) AS counts");
$this->db->order_by("counts","DESC");
$this->db->from('at_shop');
```

but it returns 0 only in the count

```
 id  shop_update count
     1   a,b,c       0
     2   a,b         0
     3   c           0
     4   a,'',c      0
```

my issue is  `LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(shop_update,',',''),'''',''))`  it was running with space like `LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(shop_update,',(spaces are added in the running query but actual code the spaces are not there) ',''),'''',''))`

Please see the difference
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
LENGTH(REPLACE(shop_update,' , ',''))
```

In your table the data is as a,b,b etc there is no space and the LENGTH is getting as same to the original string since there is nothing to replace and the line

```
LENGTH(shop_update) - LENGTH(REPLACE(shop_update,',' , ''))
```

always returns 0. i.e.

```
length of string - LENGTH(REPLACE(shop_update,',' , ''))
```

so use as

```
LENGTH(REPLACE(shop_update,',',''))
```

Comment: The space automatically to the quotes ..i duknow how this happening

Comment: You can check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f3ab3/8 to illustrate what happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
select `id`, `name`,
LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(shop_update,',',''),'''',''))
From Table1;
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92f5ab/11)**